# How can i pass some data to a ValidationFilter? [Zend 2]

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have got a ValidationFilter like Db_NoRecordExists in Zend 1.
But in some cases it's okay that there is already a record with the same value - for example when i want to update some data. Maybe the username would be still the same after updating.
But then my ValidationFilter gives an error. Now i could use something like "exclude ID XYZ".
But how can i pass that IDs to the validationfilter?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `setValidationGroup()` method to tell your form which fields it should care about.

eg if your form had 3 fields named `username`, `email` and `country`, and you don't need to validate `username` because it's not going to be changed, you can do the following in your controller (assuming `$form` is an instance of your form)

```
$form->setValidationGroup(array(
    'email',
    'country',
));
```