# ZF2 Remove Validator from ValidatorChain

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Is there a way of detaching a validator from an input? e.g.

```
$input->getValidatorChain()
    ->attach('email_address')
    ->attach('no_record_exists');

if($isExistingUser == true) {
    $input->getValidatorChain()
        ->remove('no_record_exists');
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to remove the validator? The form has a `setValidationGroup` method which can be used to ignore validation on specific fields, see for example -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300105/how-can-i-pass-some-data-to-a-validationfilter-zend-2/15313588#15313588

Comment: Yes that is a possible option, but I would still like the input to be validated. In my example I would still want to check that it is a valid email address

Comment: Ok, that's why I asked. It does pose another question though :) I'm guessing you don't want to check for dups when the email hasn't changed, but if it hasn't changed and it was valid to begin with, does it really need to be validated again? :-/

Comment: To answer your question though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252520/how-to-remove-a-validator-from-a-form-element-form-element-validatorchain-in-z, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782107/zend-framework-2-removed-form-element-causes-validation-to-fail and perhaps http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ValidatorChain-remove-and-edit-validators-td4656571.html

Comment: The second URL's method sounds like a tidy way of solving it

Answer (score 3):

```
$form->getInputFilter()->remove('no_record_exists');
```

Form being a Zend\Form\Form object

Answer (score 2):

To disable e.g. the required-validation, you can do :

$form->getInputFilter()->get('form-field')->setRequired(false);

Comment: I had to add the entity, like this way: $form->getInputFilter()->get('appointment')->get('street')->setRequired(FALSE);